# I want to check if the checkbox is checked, but everytime i try it always goes with the else option for everything

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a bookshop website where the customer checks the books and writes the number of copies. But the code cannot tell if the checkbox is checked and goes with the "else" option always. What needs to change?

checkb1-5 are the checkboxes element
numbcop1-5 is the number of copies entered by the user

```
    function Checker() {     

     var checkb1 = document.getElementById("adult");
     if (checkb1.checked){
         var numbcop1 = document.getElementById(numb1);
     } else{
         var numbcop1 = 0;
     }

     var checkb2 = document.getElementById("ado");
     if (checkb2.checked){
         var numbcop2 = document.getElementById(numb2);
     } else{
         var numbcop2 = 0;
     }

     var checkb3 = document.getElementById("child");
     if (checkb3.checked){
         var numbcop3 = document.getElementById(numb3);
     } else {
         var numbcop3 = 0;
     }

     var checkb4 = document.getElementById("school");
     if (checkb4.checked){
         var numbcop4 = document.getElementById(numb4);
     } else {
         var numbcop4 = 0;
     }

     var checkb5 = document.getElementById("transl");   
     if (checkb5.checked){
         var numbcop5 = document.getElementById(numb5);
     } else{
         var numbcop5 = 0;
     }
    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(numb1)`  is a pointer on element, not a value

Comment: Is `checked` a valid property on Element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Can you also include your html?

Comment: Code looks fine. You may want to creat and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It might help if you add the exact html for the checkboxes. Also check your console for errors (hit f12) there could be an issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is going with the if option not else but it is returning zero.
You must point to the value of the numb1 not just the element.
for example:

```
var numbcop1 = document.getElementById(numb1).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few things to fix before to make your function works:

When you are doing `var numbcop1 = document.getElementById(numb1);` you need to make sure the parameter you are adding to getElementById is correct. E.g `document.getElementById('numb1')` or make sure that numb1 contains an string indicating the id for the function to look at e.g `var numb1 = 'adult_amount';` and then use that variable as your code does `document.getElementById(numb1)`

Once you get the element that is expected to have the value, if it is an **input** you can do `var numbcop1 = document.getElementById('numb1').value;` to get the number typed by the user.

Let's refactor the Adult field to have a clear example on how it works:

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-copies="adult_copies" id="adult">
<label>adult</label>
<input type="number" id="adult_copies">
```

And add this to your ***JS*** and check how the values comes using a single function that can be reused for the other books:

```js
function getChecked(event) {
 let numbcop;
 let copies_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-copies');
 
  if (event.target.checked){
    numbcop = document.getElementById(copies_id).value;
  } else{
    numbcop = 0;
  }
  console.log(numbcop);
}


let adult = document.getElementById("adult");
adult.addEventListener('click', getChecked);
```

LMK if this works for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

at least this must be coded like this (?):

```js
var
  t_elem   = ['adult', 'ado', 'child','school', 'transl'], 
  numbcop1 = 0,
  numbcop2 = 0,
  numbcop3 = 0,
  numbcop4 = 0,
  numbcop5 = 0
  ;

function Checker() { 
  t_elem.forEach((elm,idx)=>{
    window['numbcop'+(idx+1)] = (document.getElementById(elm).checked) ? document.getElementById('numb'+(idx+1)).value : 0;
  })
}

Get_Books.onclick = function() {
  Checker();
  console.log(numbcop1, numbcop2, numbcop3, numbcop4, numbcop5);
}
```

```css
label { float:left; clear: both; display:block; width:80px; margin:10px 5px; text-align: right }
input, button  { float:left; display:block; margin:10px 5px }
button  { clear: both }
```

```html
<label for="adult">adult: </label>
<input id="adult" type="checkbox" />
<input id="numb1" type="number" value="1" />

<label for="ado">ado: </label>
<input id="ado" type="checkbox" />
<input id="numb2" type="number" value="2" />

<label for="adult">child: </label>
<input id="child" type="checkbox" />
<input id="numb3" type="number" value="3" />

<label for="school">school: </label>
<input id="school" type="checkbox" />
<input id="numb4" type="number" value="4" />

<label for="transl">transl: </label>
<input id="transl" type="checkbox" />
<input id="numb5" type="number" value="5" />

<button id="Get_Books">Books</button>
```